# Group using stream in Java 8 using Map value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to group a list of objects of class Product by its product type. Unfortunately, the way the Product class is written is like this:

```
class Product {
    Map<String, String> property;
}
```

The product class contains a map of properties, one of the properties is called "ProductType". For example, the map can contain:

```
ProductType : Machine
Price : 1000
Name : Motor Cutter
......
```

We have a list of Product. I am thinking what is the correct way to group them by ProductType into `Map<String, List<Product>>` using Java 8's stream and lamda expression.

The answer is obvious if the Product class was defined as:

```
class Product {
    String ProductType;
    Double Price;
    String Name;
}
```

But with the definition we have at the top, I have no idea how to implement this.

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you show the stream you did?

Answer (score 6):

You can still use `groupingBy` :

```
List<Product> products = ... 
Map<String, List<Product>> groups = 
     products.stream()
             .filter(p->p.property.containsKey("ProductType"))
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p->p.property.get("ProductType")));
```

I added the `filter` step to avoid `null` keys in the output `Map`.

Comment: Or use something like `groupingBy(p->p.property.getOrDefault("ProductType", "**No Type**"))`…